# How can I select a user role at the time of the account registration?

Tags: users

How can I show the field to let users choose the role when they register an account on Drupal 8?

Comment: Why would users select their own roles? This seems like a security issue waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day,

Have you tried the [Select registration roles](https://www.drupal.org/project/select_registration_roles) module? I think this would be a straightforward configuration for the role field that you want.

Hope everything is in order.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Leolando,

its working, also now how to get payment option after select the user role on same registration process.

Comment: @saravankumar: List of user roles, can that field be made required by using this module. Right now it looks like optional. ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new entity reference field (users) in account setting pages 'admin/config/people/accounts' and select Role. Form display settings can be updated to display the Roles.